# Python | How to remove sub array from 2D array

Tags: python, arrays

If I have a 2D array like:

```
array = [["hello"], [1,2,3], [4,5,6]]
```

How can I get the program to remove the first sub array so that it turns out like this:

```
array = [[1,2,3], [4,5,6]]
```

If I try to do `array[0].pop[0]`, the array ends up like this:

```
array = [[], [1,2,3], [4,5,6]]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must do

```
array.pop(0)
```

Since you want to remove the first element

Answer (score 2):

When you do `array[0].pop(0)` you are removing `"hello"` not `["hello"]` 
Since `["hello"]` is at position 0 of array you should use

```
array.pop(0)
```

Answer (score 0):

You are deleting the first item of the first sub list, not whole of the sub list. You can use `del` statement to delete the first item:

```
>>> array=[["hello"],[1,2,3],[4,5,6]]
>>> 
>>> del array[0]
>>> 
>>> array
[[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]]
```

Or if you want to preserve the deleted item you can use `array.pop(0)`.

Answer (score 0):

To remove the first item from `array` and return it use `array.pop(0)`:

```
>>> array = [["hello"], [1,2,3], [4,5,6]]
>>> array.pop(0)
['hello']
>>> array
[[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]]
```

If you're not interested in the return value, you can use slice assignment or `del`. These can be used to remove more than one item.

```
>>> array = [["hello"], [1,2,3], [4,5,6]]
>>> array[:1] = []
>>> array
[[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]]
```

Answer (score 0):

*array[0]* is the list *["hello"]*, the first (and only) item in this list is the string *"hello"*, so if you pop it you get the empty list *[]*, hence you get your result.

As mentioned the right way to pop the first list from *array* is *array.pop(0)*